# How to force a preceding 0 to an int (without actually outputting it)

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to force a preceding `0` to an `int` so it can be processed later on. Now, all the tutorials i've seen on SO, or any other website, all use something similar to this:

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << x ;
```

Whilst this is great, i can only seem to get it to work with `cout`, however, I don't want to output my text, i just want the number padded, for later use.

So far, this is my code..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

/*
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::setprecision;
using std::fixed;
using std::scientific;
using std::cin;
using std::vector;
*/
using namespace std;

void split(const string &str, vector<string> &splits, size_t length = 1)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    splits.clear();    // assure vector is empty

    while(pos < str.length())    // while not at the end
    {
        splits.push_back(str.substr(pos, length));    // append the substring
        pos += length;                                // and goto next block
    }
}

int main()
{
    int int_hour;
    vector<string> vec_hour;
    vector<int> vec_temp;

    cout << "Enter Hour: ";
    cin >> int_hour;

    stringstream str_hour;
    str_hour << int_hour;

    cout << "Hour Digits:" << endl; 
    split(str_hour.str(), vec_hour, 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < vec_hour.size(); i++)
    {
        int_hour = atoi(vec_hour[i].c_str());
        printf( "%02i", int_hour);
        cout << "\n";
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The idea being to input an `int`, then cast it to a `stringstream` to be split into single characters, then back to an integer. However, anything less than the number 10 (<10), I need to be padded with a 0 on the left.

Thanks guys

EDIT:
The code you see above is only a snippet of my main code, this is the bit im trying to make work.

Alot of people are having trouble understanding what i mean. so, here's my idea. Okay, so the entire idea of the project is to take user input (time (hour, minute) day(numeric, month number), etc). Now, i need to break those numbers down into corresponding vectors (vec_minute, vec_hour, etc) and then use the vectors to specify filenames.. so like:
   cout << vec_hour[0] << ".png";
   cout << vec_hour[1] << ".png";

Now, i know i can use for loops to handle the output of vectors, i just need help breaking down the input into individual characters. Since i ask users to input all numbers as 2 digits, anything under the number 10 (numbers preceding with a 0), wont split into to digits because the program automatically removes its preceding 0 before the number gets passed to the split method (ie. you enter 10, your output will be 10, you enter 0\n9, and your output will be a single digit 9). I cant have this, i need to pad the any number less than 10 with a 0 before it gets passed to the split method, therefore it will return 2 split digits. I cast the integers into stringstreams because thats the best way for splitting data types i found (incase you were wondering).

Hope i explained everything alot better :/

Comment: String streams work the same way as output streams.

Comment: If you're talking about padding the `int` itself with leading zeros, I'm afraid that doesn't make sense. Integers are not represented as sequences of decimal digits.

Comment: how does that not make sense? I need to add a 0 to the front left of a single digit int, before it gets parsed through to the split method. Whether the 0 gets added before or after the int is cast into the string steam doesnt matter, i just need to padd it at some point before it gets passed

Comment: You can't *pad an int* with a leading zero, as @Keith said. You can pad *the string representation of an int* with a leading `0` *character*, but you're prepending a character value to a string value, not *padding an int*. The difference is major, and you need to understand it.

Comment: why can't you just mod+divide by 10, store the resulting numbers? If you need leading zeros, push back zeros because you have a set power of 10 you are trying to reach

Comment: In fact a sufficiently small `int` is *already* zero-padded. Assuming 8 bits for simplicity, the value `13` (decimal) will be stored as a sequence of bits: `0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1`.  You can construct a *character string* representing that value in decimal as `"13"`, or `"013"`, or `"0000013"` if you like. Constructing that string will require a fair amount of arithmetic computation, which is typically hidden by whatever library routine you use to do the job.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you can just use those manipulators with a `stringstream`, for instance:

```
std::stringstream str_hour;
str_hour << setfill('0') << setw(2) << int_hour;
```

String streams are output streams, so I/O manipulators affect them the same way they affect the behavior of `std::cout`.

A complete example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << 10; // Prints 10
    ss << " - ";
    ss << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << 5; // Prints 05

    std::cout << ss.str();
}
```

And the corresponding [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2b9520951de40584828f52e93303ce94-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc).

Comment: okay so i set up a test script, that basically checks to see if the input is 1 character long, and if it is, then it will try your script. 

And if i input 9, the output of str_hour.str(); will be "909"

Any idea why and how to fix it ?

Comment: I cant use a separate stringstream can i? I have to handle about 12 different ints being split 1 after the other.. unless, i just overwrite stringstream ss every time ?

Comment: @amartin94: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "splitting an int"? And what do you have to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`int` and other numeric types store **values**. Sticking a `0` in front of an integer value does not change the value. It's only when you convert it to a text representation that adding a leading `0` changes what you have, because you've changed the text representation by inserting an additional character.

Answer (score -1):

X-Y Problem, I think

```
for ( int i = 0; i < POWER_OF_TEN; i++ )
{
  vector<int>.push_back(num%10);
  num /= 10
}
```

?

Then reverse the vector if you want

yes i know this is not real code

if you really want characters, `vector<char>.push_back(num%10 + '0')`?